# Model Cache EntityFrameWork in aspnetboilerplate Error Filter name MustHaveTenant not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, aspnetboilerplate

I want to minimize the time taken by the first query of entity-framework by using the Cached model as some blogs and StackOverflow answers suggested.
I am using aspnetboiler 3.8.1 asp.net MVC and entity-framework 6.2
I added DB configuration like this

```
 public MyContextConfiguration()
    {
        var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(this.GetType().Assembly.Location);
        SetModelStore(new DefaultDbModelStore(path));
    }
```

and set this configuration to DbConext like this

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyContextConfiguration))]
public class MyDbContext : AbpZeroDbContext<Tenant, Role, User>
{
```

The first time project Ran fine and created cache but after that, it gives the following error

> System.ApplicationException: 'Filter name MustHaveTenant not found'

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbpPq.png)

I searched for this error and found that this error usually comes when you do not call
a base class OnCreate in the DbContext OnCreate ([Source](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/456)). But I am calling the base class constructor

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        //Database.Log = (query) => Debug.Write(query);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Movement>()
            .HasMany<Mark>(mov => mov.InMarks)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(c =>
            {
                c.MapLeftKey("MovementId");
                c.MapRightKey("MarkId");
                c.ToTable("MovementInMarks");
            });
```

This only comes when the application tries to load the model from cache otherwise it is working fine
Does anyone has resolved this type of error in aspnetboilerplate
Thanks

Comment: Share a repro project on GitHub that is forked from [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template).

Comment: https://github.com/codertrap1/AbpIssue.git

Comment: I recreated same error in it first time it will run and second time when it will try to load model from cache it will give error of filter name

Comment: This is latest asp .net MVC 5 +angular js aspnetboilerplate project only changes are in SpeedTest.EntityFramework project one change is I added Configuration file and Second change I gave configuration to db context

Comment: Where is `GetCultureFromTenantSetting`?